# I got this error when trying to load a image file in js

Tags: javascript, image, png, mime

> I wrote this in my code

```
import grass from './assets/grass.png';
console.log(grass);
```

> But the chrome console says this thing below

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "image/png". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

Comment: You can import only JavaScript modules (aka js files) .

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? **Import** has a specific purpose for importing javascript modules and nothing else.

Comment: OP probably have seen this syntax when used with webpack or another bundler. Bundlers can load images like this.

Comment: Can you change to a more descriptive title? Ex. "chrome console cannot ESM import image file" (ESM stands for ECMAScript Module)

Answer (score 0):

Tools like Webpack support the use of `import` statements for images.

They perform preprocessing of the image at build time and generate a URL pointing to where the image will be deployed (or sometimes a data scheme URL to inline it).

It doesn’t make sense to try to do that at runtime.

Browsers **only** support the importing of JavaScript modules (although there are proposals for other kinds of resource such as JSON).

If you want to use an image, then ./assets/grass.png is already the final URL, so just use that string directly without putting it anywhere near an import statement.

Comment: so what do i do now

Comment: @GT-20 — Do what I told you to do in the last paragraph of this answer.